# How to test child component render after api call on react testing library

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, axios, jestjs, react-testing-library

I want to test the child component render after click a display detail button. When click the button, it will call api `getPokemonDetail` to get the Pokemon detail and then change the `PokemonDetail` state.

The app is running well. But on my unit test, I can only get the `Loading` text after button click. I used `axios-mock-adapter` to mock axios request. If I disable the axios mock, it's running correct. Looks like the axios mock is not working after button click. How should I fix it? The below is my code.

Parent Component:

```
const getPokemonDetail = async (pokemonName) => {
    const queryName = pokemonName ?? "ditto"
    try {
        const result = await axios.get(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${queryName}`)
        console.log(result.data)
        const { name, id, weight } = result.data
        return Promise.resolve({ name, id, weight })
    } catch (error) {
        return undefined
    }
}
const ParentComponent = (props) => {
    const { pokemonName } = props
    const [pokemonDetail, setPokemonDetail] = useState({
        detail: null,
        loading: true,
    })
    const retrieveDisplayStatus = async () => {
        const getPokemonDetailResult = await getPokemonDetail(pokemonName)
        if (getPokemonDetailResult) {
            setPokemonDetail({
                detail: getPokemonDetailResult,
                loading: false,
            })
        }
    }
    const { showDetails, toggleDetails } = useToggleDetails(retrieveDisplayStatus)
    return (
        <>
            <h2>Display Pokemon Detail</h2>
            <button onClick={toggleDetails}>Display Detail</button>
            <>
                {showDetails ? (
                    <>{
                        pokemonDetail.loading ? 
                          <div>Loading...</div> : 
                          <ChildComponent pokemonDetail={pokemonDetail.detail} />
                      }</>
                ) : null}
            </>
        </>
    )
}
```

Child Component:

```
const ChildComponent = (props) => {
    const { pokemonDetail } = props
    const { id, name, weight } = pokemonDetail
    return (
        <>
            <div>ChildComponent</div>
            <div data-testid="testId">id: {id}</div>
            <div>name: {name}</div>
            <div>weight: {weight}</div>
        </>
    )
}
export default ChildComponent
```

On the Parent component test:

```
import { render, screen } from "@testing-library/react"
import ParentComponent from "../ParentComponent"
import userEvent from "@testing-library/user-event"
import axios from "axios"
import MockAdapter from "axios-mock-adapter"

describe("test", () => {
    let mock
    beforeAll(() => {
        mock = new MockAdapter(axios)
    })
    afterEach(() => {
        mock.reset()
    })
    test("Render child component after api call", async () => {
        render(<ParentComponent />)
        const heading = screen.getByText("Display Pokemon Detail")
        expect(heading).toBeInTheDocument()
        const toggleButton = screen.getByRole("button", { name: /display/i })
        expect(toggleButton).toBeInTheDocument()
        userEvent.click(toggleButton)
        const loadingText = await screen.findByText(new RegExp("Loading", "i"))
        expect(loadingText).toBeInTheDocument()
        // the below is not working, looks like the axios mock not working
        mock.onGet(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/ditto`).reply(200, { name: "ditto", id: 132, weight: 40 })
        const childHeading = await screen.findByText("ChildComponent")
        expect(childHeading).toBeInTheDocument()
        const id = await screen.findByTestId("testId")
        expect(id).toHaveTextContent("132")
    })
})
```